# Where does Gas Mask store its data on OSX?

Tags: macos, hosts-file

I use [Gas Mask](http://www.clockwise.ee/gasmask/) to manage my hosts file on OSX. Where does it store its data?

Answer (score 1):

Gas Mask stores its data in `~/Library/Gas Mask/`. Here's an example of what you'll see there:

```
$ ls ~/Library/Gas Mask/
Combined/
Local/
Remote/
```